# Submit form with a button outside the form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form which I use a button outside the form to submit.
Below is the code on how I submit the form with a button from outside the form. The code below should echo something on the page. But I don't know why my text wont echo.

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['partForm'])){
        echo "Test1";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submitForm'])){
        echo "Test2";
    }
?>

<html>
<body>

<div>
<h2>Part</h2>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="partForm" id="partForm" action="submit_form_button_outside.php">
SKU#: <input type="text" name="sku"><br>
Part: <select name="categories">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
<option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select><br>

Description: <input type="text" name="part"><br>
Quantity: <input type="text" name="part"><br>
Price: <input type="text" name="part"><br>
Select images: <input type="file" name="img" multiple><input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</div>

<div>
    <button type="submit" form="partForm" value="submitForm">Add Item</button>
    <!--<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('partForm').submit();">Add Item</button>-->
    <!--<button type="button" onclick="document.forms['partForm'].submit(); return false">Add Item</button> -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, all your (text type) inputs have the same name `name="part"` - Second, you haven't defined any variables, so don't expect them to be echo'ed. Third, your form being named `partForm` won't pass for your `if(isset...`

Comment: If you have many inputs with the same name you should at least use `parts[]` in the name

Comment: @Sergio My sentiments exactly.

Comment: Plus, if you want to use a submit button outside your form, you may have a chance in using Ajax/JS for that and call it as a function to it. I doubt very much that your "new way of doing things" will work. So, why try and re-invent the wheel? (*as it were*) - at the very least name this `<button type="submit" form="partForm" value="submitForm">` needs to be named `<button type="submit" form="partForm" value="submitForm" name="submitForm">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values that will be in the POST array will be the names of the posted elements. I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think the form name will be in the $_POST array.

You can check for a post by using

```
if (!empty($_POST))
{

}
```

or you can check for individual values like $_POST['sku'] based on the input names within the FORM

Answer (score 8):

You could use the jQuery submit function like:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
    $('#partForm').submit();
});
```

Basically, when the outside button is clicked, the form is submitted.

Comment: Why is jQuery (that is not asked for) the solution here?

Comment: yes but user could be specific about the code requirement to be pure javascript and no library while asking the question

Comment: Of course it's not asked for, if was asked for, he would know the answer. Of course the anwswer i could have given more complet, but a downvote it's really unfairly.

Answer (score 2):

Your button is outside the form tag.

If you want your button outside the form tags consider the following example:

```
<form action="demo_form.php" method="get" id="form1">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
</form>

<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Note the form attribute on the button.

Next thing to check for is if the posted variables are set:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

your code is working well , and the form is submitting , but you are testing a wrong values in $_POST['partForm'] , try to fill the value sku ,, and in ur php test $_POST['sku']

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button outside the form, you wil lnot be able to submit the form with that button without using javascript.

The code I see lower down does look about right:
    Add Item

I assume that did not work. Did you veriufy that the form did submit? I think the form name is not always passed in the $_POST array. Better test for one of the elements, or just print_r($_POST); to show the submitted info.