# .submit not working in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
<!-- jQuery / jQueryMobile Scripts -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        // Attach a submit handler to the form
        $("#loginForm").submit(function (event) {

            // Stop form from submitting normally
            event.preventDefault();

            // Get some values from elements on the page:
            var $form = $(this),
              username = $form.find("input[name='username']").val(),
               password = $form.find("input[name='password']").val(),
              url = $form.attr("action");

            // Send the data using post
            var posting = $.post(url, { username: username, password: password });

            // Put the results in a div
            posting.done(function (data) {
                var content = $(data).find("#content");
                $("#result").empty().append(content);
            });
        });

</script>



  <div data-role="page" data-theme='b' id="1">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" data-theme='b'>
        <a href="index.html" data-ajax="false"><i class='fa fa-bars'></i></a>
        <h1>Glue Plus+</h1>
    </div>



    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="inset">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="http://url/Sugar/php_Calls/login.php" id="loginForm" data-ajax="false">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="name2b">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" name="username" id="emailaddress" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Type your email here...">
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="name2b">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="Type your password here...">
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">

                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1a" id="checkbox-1ab" checked="">
                <label for="checkbox-1ab">Keep me logged in</label>

            </div>
        </form>

        <button type="submit" id="btnlogin" name="login" href="#mainpage" data-inline="true">Submit</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

It's not coming inside the form submit when i debug through firebug

Comment: Please post your HTML also..

Comment: You need to use a DOM ready handler or move the script to after the HTML for the form.

Comment: wrap code in `pagecreate` event `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () { rest of code });`. Dont use plain numbers as `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button is outside the form scope. You can fix this with the help of `form="loginForm"`:

```
<button type="submit" form="loginForm" id="btnlogin" name="login" href="#mainpage" data-inline="true">Submit</button>
```

[There are many questions like yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435670/submit-form-with-a-button-outside-the-form). Next time do a search before you post.

Answer (score -1):

You need either put button inside form or add form attribute

```
<button type="submit" id="btnlogin" ... form="loginForm">Submit</button>
```

And as @Anthoy Grist pointed you need either put script after markup or use ready event.

```
$(function() {
    $("#loginForm").submit(function (event) { 
    ...
});
```